# How can I change my Bibliography to enumerate the supplemental references like [S1], [S2],...,instead of [1],[2],

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I'm writing a scientific paper, using `\documentclass[aps,prl,...]{revtex4-1}` with supplemental Material. The Supplemental Material is an extra tex file and I want that the references there to be numbered like [S1],[S2],...
I'm using `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}`.
Is there any way doing it like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you want to create a separate bibliography for the supplemental materials, or should the `[S.]` entries be listed alongside the other entries in the main bibliography?

Comment: I want to create a new .bib file.

Comment: Florian -- I think @Mico was asking something slightly different.  He wants to know whether the '[S<num>]' entries should appear in the same printed bibliography as the regular '[<num>]' entries, not whether they will be in a separate bibliography database (i.e., a new `.bib` file).  That is, will the document contain one bibliography or two?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my descriptioin wasn't clear enough. The supplemental material will be an extra tex file, which has it's own references and thus it's own seperate bib-file. I just want the references in the SM to be numbered like [Sx] instead if [x].

Answer (score 7):

As REVTeX uses [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib), you can use the mechanisms provided by that package to make this change

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{demo,
  author  = "Other, A. N.",
  journal = "J. Irrep. Res.",
  year    = 2012,
  pages   = "1-10",
  volume  = "200"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[aps,prl]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\renewcommand*{\citenumfont}[1]{S#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[S#1]}
\begin{document}
\cite{demo}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

(I do something similar in [`achemso`](http://ctan.org/pkg/achemso)).

Comment: @Florian -- Best to accept the answer and thereby mark it as 'solved'.